# How to see if some condition is met, and based on that to display result

Tags: sql, oracle

I have database(university) in which I need to see if two lectures have the same teacher, or not, and based on that I need to display answer("yes" && "no").

My question is, how can I display it? I always thought that I can put only colum names?

Before posting this question, I looked at google to se if there is anyting helpful there, and the only thing I found was the case statment, which was not too helpful, becuse I am always getting error messages when calling some function(exists, ...).

Comment: Post your table strucutre

Comment: Use a case statement to determine the output value: `case when (boolean condition that checks if lectures are shared) then "yes" else "no" end as SharedLecture`

Answer (score 5):

You could use a `case` statement:

```
select  case 
        when l1.Teacher = l2.Teacher then 'yes'
        else 'no'
        end
from    lectures l1
cross join    
        lectures l2
where   l1.name = 'Quantum Mechanics'
        and l2.name = 'Buddhism II'
```

Comment: if the user dont know the subject names then we can use l1.name!=l2.name.....? @andomar